# Using dijit.form.DateTextBox Not able to retain proper Time value

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, dojo

I am using dijit.form.DateTextBox to update my date field.

```
<form:input id="date_id" name="date_field" path="createDate"
                                dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                                disabled="false" constraints="{datePattern:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'}"
                                invalidMessage="invalid" promptMessage="invalid"
                                lang="en-us" required="true"/>
```

now, suppose If my `'createDate'` value is `'05/01/2012 21:10:17.287'`, but it is displaying as `'05/01/2012 12:00:00.00'` in date text box.
Due to which, while editing this field, I'm not able to keep it as it was.

Is there anyway I can retain that time part `'21:10:17.287'`.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This solution will work for above Dojo 1.6 versions )

The default `DateTextBox` overrides the old value when setting a new one. This means that the time context is lost while setting the value. If you want to make this possible, you will have to extend the default behavior of the `_setValueAttr` function of `DateTextBox` since this is the setter of the `value` field.

This is how you could do this:

```
declare("custom.DateTextBox", [DateTextBox], {
    _setValueAttr: function(value, priorityChange, formattedValue) {
        if(value !== undefined){
            if(typeof value == "string"){
                value = stamp.fromISOString(value);
            }
            if(this._isInvalidDate(value)){
                value = null;
            }
            if(value instanceof Date && !(this.dateClassObj instanceof Date)){
                value = new this.dateClassObj(value);
            }
        }
        if (value != null && this.value != null) {
            value.setHours(this.value.getHours());
            value.setMinutes(this.value.getMinutes());
            value.setSeconds(this.value.getSeconds());
            value.setMilliseconds(this.value.getMilliseconds());
        }
        this.value = value;
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});
```

What happens here is pretty easy, the first thing I do is parsing the new value to a valid `Date`. Before replacing the original value I'm copying the time fields (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds).

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/dYspp/) to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually I forgot to mention I'm using dojo 1.6, This code is working fine on 1.7 above.. can you pls suggest changes for 1.6. I tried but it did not worked.

Comment: Use `dojo.declare` in stead of `declare`.

Comment: yup that I tried, But it says

TypeError: modulename.split is not a function
'var syms = modulename.split(".");'

Comment: You might have to replace `[DateTextBox]` by `dijit.form.DateTextBox` too.

Comment: I noticed there are several differences between Dojo 1.6 and the new(er) implementations. You wil need to look at the source code and find out if there's a function more appropriate for saving the time.